# Displaying survey results with frequency and percentages

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to write a display of the servey results that look like:

```
decription   frequency  percentage
is too slow 1   .5
is too fast 1   .5
is just right   0    0
I don't know    0    0
```

but have been stuck with this:

decription   frequency  percentage

```
is too slow 2   1.0000
is too fast 2   1.0000
is just right   2   1.0000
I don't know    2   1.0000
```

My query looks is currently:

```
SELECT Question_Choices.Choice_description, count(answers.Seq_num) as frequency, (count(answers.Seq_num)/sum(answers.Seq_num)) as percentage
FROM Question_Choices
INNER JOIN answers ON Question_Choices.qid=answers.qid
group by Question_Choices.Choice_description;
```

with the table schemas being

```
Answers(Seq_num, Choice_id, qid)

PK(Seq_num, Choice_id, qid)
FK1 Seq_num ref Responce_Person(Seq_num)
FK2 (Choice_id, qid) ref Question_Choices(Choice_id, qid)

Question_Choices(choice_id, Choice_text, qid)

    PK(Choice_id, qid)
    FK qid ref Questions(qid)
```

I know I need to include `Answers.Choice_id = Question_Choices.Choice_id` somewhere but I'm lost as to how

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: I'm lost as well. Are you using compound keys? Provide sample data as formatted text tables https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support.